# What is this random white dot in only one photo of Eagle Nebula stack?

Tags: astrophotography

A few hours ago, I've taken 178 images of the Eagle Nebula/Omega Nebula area of the milky way using Canon EOS 5D Mark IV, iOptron SkyTracker, and Canon EF70-200mm f/2.8L lens.

As I'll be stacking around 180 shots, I've bumped up the ISO all the way to ISO 32000 and the photos are undoubtably noisy. However, when I was cycling through the photos with my friend, my friend spotted a white dot near the Eagle Nebula in only one shot. It's definitely not noise (see bottom middle towards a little right):

[image]

[image]

That dot is more than a single pixel, exists in one and only one photo, and has a something-bursting-in-two-directions like shape.

It's obviously not a plane, nor I think it's a satellite.

We are not pros in deep space astrophotography and maybe it's a very simple thing. But just out of curiosity: what is that dot?

**UPDATE:** I've highlighted the area of interest in the second shot. My settings are: 200mm focal length, 6s exposure, f/4.0, ISO 32000. The photo was taken at location 38.226838, 26.338415 and time 26.09.2017 23:11:34 GMT+3.

Comment: For future reference it would be helpful to highlight the area of the images you want people to see.  In this case I had to scroll up and down a lot to try and see what you meant.

Comment: What was the shutter speed of that shot / each shot?

Comment: @StephenG I've added the area of interest. my bad, sorry. fixed it now :)

Comment: @scottbb I've added all the details. see my updated question

Comment: *"It's obviously not a plane, nor I think it's a satellite."*  Not obvious at all, and you give no justification for this arbitrary assumption.  A satellite is actually the most likely answer.  Why would you think this is *not* a satellite?

Comment: @OlinLathrop It's obviously not a plane as it just flashed and disappeared high above (so no takeoff/landing lights and also no probes as it was a one-time flash), also it's not moving (it *could* be very high and would seem stationary in the photo, though I see no way of it flashing once and disappearing forever if it's a plane, especially about 4 hours after sunset where it can't reflect sunlight). I said I don't *think* it's a satellite because, again it flashed once for a brief moment and disappeared. I though it's unlikely that it could rotate so fast to reflect sunlight for a split sec.

Comment: @OlinLathrop again, I'm not a pro in the field, that's why I'm asking it here. I just represented my though. it can of course be incorrect, therefore I said "I *think*", not "*it is*".  I'm here to learn and open for educative explanations for sure :)

Comment: Migrate to [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).  These questions pop up a lot there and they're quite used to them (but your photo and detailed data will make answering a lot easier for them than typical questions they get).

Comment: First, you never said how long each exposure was, so a single strobe from a plane or even a fixed light for a short exposure couldn't be ruled out.  Second, satellites can have flat reflective surfaces.  A satellite doesn't have to rotate fast at all for you to see a brief flash of sun reflection at any one spot on the ground.  Imagine someone a  mile away slowly panning a pocket mirror, with the reflection of the sun being roughly in your direction.  You'd only see a short flash at most.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I see, so it's probably a satellite then? (and just for the sake of completeness, the exposure and other metadata are there in the question. It's 6 seconds of exposure per frame.)

Answer (score 1):

There is this thing called Iridium Flare, it is basically sunlight reflecting on large surfaces of manmade satellites (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare).

Those flares can be quite bright, maybe that is your spot. I think you can find calculators for your time and location of imaging to see whether there where any Iridium Flares visible.

Comment: At that sensitivity I tend to think an Iridium Flare photographed from anywhere near the center of the ground track would have been multiple orders of magnitude brighter. Certainly bright enough to have cause blooming over a much larger area than the light seen in the example.

Comment: You are right. It might have been the edge, or just beginning or end of the flare though. It would help to know the shutter speed and also time gaps between the shots. Iridium and other satellites of course would produce a trail with long enough shutter speeds.

Comment: since a tracking mount was used I'm assuming longer shutter times.

Comment: @MichaelClark it's 6 seconds. see my updated question, I've added more details.

Comment: @smow I've used the following link: http://www.heavens-above.com/IridiumFlares.aspx?lat=38.2276&lng=26.3385&loc=Unnamed+Road&alt=10&tz=TRT it doesn't show any flares for yesterday night at anywhere those times

Comment: Keep in mind that there are other satellites besides the Iridium satellites. I'm not sure if those web sites would track spy satellites, either. You might ask on the [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) what it could have been.